# How to make R script jump to the next line?

Tags: r

The last line of my script creates a table

```
write.xlsx(res, file="C:/Users/salahmed/Desktop/test/res6.xlsx", row.names=FALSE);
```

But after I run the whole script, the cursor remains stuck at the end of this line and the table is not created. It moves to the next line (with the > symbol) only if I press Enter and only then the table is created in the folder. How do I make it automatically move to the next line without having to press Enter?

Comment: Why do you have a ```;``` at the end there? Can you show a bit more of the code before and after?

Comment: how do you run your script?

Comment: Well, I'm pretty new to R language and just found out one minute ago that the semi-colon doesn't make a difference. I just put it in there to mark the end of that statement. There is no code after this. As I said, it's the last line.

Comment: @glagla I just copy paste the whole script from a text document into R and press Enter. Then what I mentioned in my question happens in the end.

Comment: maybe just add a blank line after it. If you are mayking a copy paste to execute your script and the line you showed is the last one you selected, it won't be executed. So extend your selection until the blank line and I guess it should work

Comment: also, if you're using Rstudio, the ctrl + enter should execute everything which is selected.

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem was solved by adding a blank line at the end of the script.